# Custom post type hierarchy with 3 levels

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, hierarchy, taxonomy, genesis

There are several Sections (first custom post, I guess).
Each section has several folders (second custom post).
Each section has several articles (3rd custom post),
How can I integrate this hierarchy ?

Thx in advance

Comment: check this link:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169154/is-there-a-way-to-set-different-post-templates-for-parent-posts-and-child-posts